# Pl/SQL Nested Procedure Exception Handling

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, exception

This is a best practice question on error handling through multiple levels of PL/SQL procedures. I've looked at a few other questions to help me out, in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360565/pl-sql-exception-handling-in-procedures).

Currently, I have a program with Procedure 1, which calls Procedure 2, which calls Procedure 3. I'm trying to perform adequate error handling - but I'd like to output eventually the exact problem back to the application layer. I'm hoping to get some ideas on how I can do this efficiently and clearly.

My current solution method is below, but it seems rather messy to me, with lots of variable declarations. I am very new to PL/SQL (and SQL in general) so I'd appreciate any advice on:

1. Good error handling techniques when dealing with multiple layers of procedures.
2. Feeding error messages back up to application layer (in my procedure below, represented by "out_overall_output" variable.

Program Flow:    UI -> Proc 1 -> Proc 2 -> Proc 3

**Procedure 1:**

```
--One input variable, one output.
in_id                VARCHAR2;
out_overall_output   VARCHAR2;
...
DECLARE
    l_success         BOOLEAN;
    l_error_output    VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    Proc2(id, l_success, l_error_output);
    IF l_success = FALSE THEN
        out_overall_output = l_error_output
    END IF
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    out_overall_output:= 'Error calling Proc 2'
    RETURN;
END;
--Normal flow continues if l_success is true...
```

**Procedure 2:**

```
-- One input variable, two output.
in_id
out_success
out_error_output
//other logic
DECLARE
    l_success         BOOLEAN;
    l_error_output    VARCHAR2(100)
BEGIN
    Proc3(id, l_success, l_error_output)
    IF l_success = FALSE THEN
        out_error_output = l_error_output
    END IF
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS
    out_error_output = 'Error calling Proc 3'
    RETURN;
END;
```

**Procedure 3:**

```
--One input variable, two output.
in_id                VARCHAR2;
out_success          BOOLEAN;
out_error_message    VARCHAR2;
...
BEGIN
    DELETE 
    FROM table
    WHERE id = in_id;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    out_success = FALSE;
    out_error_message = 'Error - No data to delete'
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    out_success = FALSE;
    out_error_message = 'Error deleting data.'
END;
```

Note: The levels of procedure calling goes deeper than this. The snippets I have shown are greatly simplified. The error messages and variable names in my real procedures are more descriptive.

Comment: Generally, you should avoid passing errors via parameters and instead pass errors between procedures using `RAISE` and/or `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`. In your examples you are masking the error as soon as it happens, which means that when you get an unexpected error, you won't have any idea what the real error was.

Comment: @Allan: Could you explain that in a bit more detail for me? To my understanding, if I get a "when others" error in Procedure 3, I'm keeping track of that and passing it up the chain. Does that not mean I'll not what the real error was?

Comment: Under the last procedure above, in the case of an `OTHERS` error, you always get the message "Error calling Proc 2". Was it a numeric overflow error? A type conversion error? A distributed transaction error? There are literally thousands of error messages that it could be. You're hiding all of that information by replacing the error with a generic message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show exact explanations of "what happens with a server" for application level you can try following. In procedures:

```
create or replace procedure p1 is
...
exception
  when <some_error> then
    <do something>
    -- re-raise error:
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Client with ID '|| ID || ' has no right to perform action "' || ACTION_NAME || '"', true);
end;

create or replace procedure p2 is
begin
  p1;
exception
  when <another_error> then
    <do something>
    -- re-raise error:
    raise_application_error(-20002, 'Action "' || ACTION_NAME || '" is not completed', true);
end;

create or replace procedure p3 is
begin
  p2;
exception
  when <another_error> then
    <do something>
    -- re-raise error:
    raise_application_error(-20003, 'Purchasing of "' || CAR_NAME || '" cancelled', true);
end;
```

And in top level procedure:

```
create or replace procedure top_level_procedure is
begin
  p1;
exception
  when <one_more_error> then
    <do something>
    raise_application_error(-20004, dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
end;
```

After exception in `p1` you will see something like this:

```
ORA-20003: Purchasing of "Cool red Ferrari" cancelled
ORA-20002: Action "car purchase" is not completed
ORA-20001: Client with ID 123 has no right to perform action "Spent all money of Bill Gates"
```

Third parameter of procedure `raise_application_error` with `false` value cuts all previous error messages. If you will use false value in procedure `p3`, you will see only one error message with code `ORA-20003` in this example.

P. S. Also you can define your own exceptions and use them in `WHEN .. THEN` clause. Here you find more information and examples: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#LNPLS00704

P. P. S. How to log. Log procedure:

```
create or replace procedure log(p_log_message varchar2) is
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  insert into log_table(..., log_message) values (..., p_log_message);
  commit;
end;
```

Call log procedure:

```
  when <one_more_error> then
    <do something>
    log(..., dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    raise_application_error(-20004, dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, where would you recommend logging in the examples you've given? Just before raising the application error each time, or at the very end at the top level?

Comment: And if the answer is to do the logging at the top level, how could you log that entire raise_application_error snippet?

Comment: In this example (and most of others), I think, it is better to do logging once at a top level (one transaction instead of three), but I can't say that it is the only possible solution.

Comment: I added example to post. `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace` is a function, that returns "full story" of exceptions during procedure call. You can put its value to a variable and do after that all what you want.