# Scope and correct use of SQLERRM? (Handling Exception PL/SQL, ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, stored-procedures, plsql

I've some doubts about handling exception in a oracle stored procedure, specifically, about sqlerrm use. Let me explain.

According oracle official documentation, sqlerrm is a function that:

*"..returns the error message associated with the most recently raised error exception. This function should only be used within the Exception Handling section of your code."*

The oracle exception syntax is:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN exception_name1 THEN
      [statements]
   WHEN exception_name_n THEN
      [statements]
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      [statements] --Here use SQLERRM and do a trace
END;
```

Usually, SQLERRM is used when happens a not controlled exception.

Now what happened with exception handling when you are call some functions exposed to exceptions into a stored procedure?

Let me explain with an example:

```
--Create a packague
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE AS

FUNCTION F1() RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
    --do querys and return a value
END F1;

FUNCTION F2() RETURN NUMBER IS 
BEGIN
    --do querys and return a value
END F2;

FUNCTION F3() RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
    --do querys and return a value
END F3;

PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(v_mssg_err OUT VARCHAR2) IS
    v1 NUMBER; v2 NUMBER; v3 VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    v1 := FUNCTION1();
    v2 := FUNCTION2();
    v3 := FUNCTION3();
    v_mssg_err := 'OK';

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        --If an error happens in F1(),F2() or F3()
        v_mssg_err := sqlerrm; 
        -- I think this is a correct way to handle exceptions
END MY_PROCEDURE;
END MY_PACKAGE;
```

I suppose that SQlERRM return the error message occurred in F1(),F2() or F3().

BUT, I've received one package where exceptions are being handling for each function declared in package. This way.

```
FUNCTION F4() RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    response VARCHAR2(1000); --511 is the max length possible for SQLERRM
BEGIN
    --do querys and return a string value
    RETURN response;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        response := TO_CHAR(-1)||sqlerrm;       
END F4;
```

I'am not sure that this be a efficient way to handling exception. Because for each stored procedure where that functions are call, it's necesary split and check the values returns.

**Backing to my question**

what it's the scope and the correct exception handling in a stored procedure that call multiple functions ? Thanks so much for help!

**Sources:**

1. Oracle: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/sqlerrm.php
2. SQLERRM Length: http://matt.gizma.com/2006/08/a_varchar2_511_to_hold_sqlerrm.html

Comment: I would prefer `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE`  or related function/procedures over `SQLERRM`.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_util.htm#i1003874 . In Oracle 12c, you also have `UTL_CALL_STACK` with a wide range of interface for exception handling.

Comment: Please take a look on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912141/pl-sql-nested-procedure-exception-handling That question is a bit different, but I think the answer could be helpful for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pl/SQL Nested Procedure Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912141/pl-sql-nested-procedure-exception-handling)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of error and how you want to manage it. Your exception will be caught by the closest enclosing block (or the block itself) which has an exception handler for that exception.

If you are catching the exception right into F1(), it means you want to deal with the exception from there. Your main procedure will then be able to continue executing F2, F3 and so on. If you catch F1()'s exception from the main procedure though, the execution will stop right there, so it won't be able to call the other functions.

Please note also that you need to put a return statement into the exception handling of your functions, or it will throw an exception (ORA-06503) when you execute it.